# Acomodar Arrays de consulta

Tags: php, sql, crud

Necesito orientación para poder acomodar los campos de una consulta SQL en estructura HTML,

Al hacer la consulta e imprimirlos mediamte `print_r($persona)` me muestra todos los datos en el header como es esperado `(Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 165 [nombre] => Ejemplo [apellido] => Ejemplo, etc..)`, el asunto es que he intentado llamar los campos que trae la consulta dentro del contenido html pero no se imprime, como por ejemplo `<?php echo $persona->apellido; ?>`, `<?php echo ['apellido']; ?>` o `<?php echo $apellido; ?>`

Les comparto esructura de la consulta:

index.php (login):

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'sys/dbConnect.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "") {
    header("Location: home.php");
}

if (isset($_POST['login_btn'])) {
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $row = $crud->getUser($usuario);

    if ($row['password'] == $password) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['nombre'];
        header("Location: home.php?nombre=" . $_SESSION['user']);
    } else {

        echo' ';
    }

}
?>
```

home.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'sys/dbConnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}


if (!isset($_GET['nombre'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

include 'sys/conexion.php';
$nombre = $_GET['nombre'];


$sentencia = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM registro WHERE nombre = '".$_SESSION['user']."'");
$sentencia->execute([$nombre]);
$persona = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
print_r($persona); (desde aquí si imprime los datos)

?>
```

La idea principal es hacer uso de una plantilla Dashboard donde el usuario pueda ver sus datos previamente registrados en la bdd. (por el momento las pruebas son en documentos limpios)

En cuanto al error_log no me genera nada extraño

Alguna idea del error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error proviene en tu respuesta.

Si lees la [documentación de fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php), notarás que en **valores devueltos**, lo que regresa es un array con todos los elementos que coincide.

En tu `print` se puede notar claramente que `$persona` es un arreglo, por lo que si tu haces esto

```
print($persona[0]->nombre);
```

ya debería imprimirte el nombre, esto porque como mencioné,  `$persona` es un arreglo y al ponerle el indice 0, estás obteniendo el primer objeto que en este caso ya es el que trae la información

también podrías intentar con `fetchObject()` en lugar de `fetchAll()`, para que te dejo la info de [fetchObject](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) para que lo leas

Comment: Perfecto!, leeré la doucmentación que me recomiendas, gracias hermano.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta algo como:

```
$persona->{'nombre'};
```

Comment: Me genera en el log  Trying to get property 'nombre' of non-object